# How to concat a regex expression with a string variable?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression as below:

```
var myVar = "some text";

var decimal = /^\s*(\+|-)?((\d+(\,\d+)?)|(\,\d+))\s*$/;
```

How to concat it with the myVar variable which is a string?

I tried the below but didn't work:

```
var decimal = new RegExp("/^\s*(\+|-)?((\d+(\" + myVar + "\d+)?)|(\" + myVar + "\d+))\s*$/");
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you want the resulting regex to match?

Comment: Apologies, I updated what is required exactly. Basically the "," should be replaced with the myVar.

Comment: Are you basically trying to make a pattern that will match `1,23` in one locale and `1.23` in another? I'd suggest using some i18n library like [this](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/) or [this](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/jsworld.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add `/` at the beginning and the end of `new RegExp(...)` and `\` should be escaped as mentioned by anubhava :

```
var decimal = new RegExp("^\\s*(\\+|-)?((\\d+(" + myVar + "\\d+)?)|(" + myVar + "\\d+))\\s*$");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just from concatenation exercise you can do this:

```
var decimal = new RegExp("^(\\s*(\\+|-)?((\\d+(,\\d+)?)|(,\\d+))\\s*)" + myVar + "$");
```

Though keep in mind that `myVar` can contain special regex meta characters as well that need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to escape the backslashes inside the string.

```
var decimal = new RegExp("/^\\s*(\\+|-)?((\\d+(\\,\\d+)?)|(\\,\\d+))\\s*$/" + myVar);
```